# How to update status field from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update `status` column to paid , where status column="closed" in my `Subscriptions` table.
Any help is appreciated

i tried like this
`Subscriptions.where(:status =>'closed').update(:status => 'paid')`
but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guest your model is `Subscription` but not `Subscriptions`

Therefore you should try

```
Subscription.where(status: 'closed').update_all(status: 'paid')
```

but not

```
 Subscriptions.where(status: 'closed').update_all(status: 'paid')
```

However, if you want your records to run callback (ex: you've set some `after_save` method), you should use below script to evoke callback.

```
Subscription.where(status: 'closed').each{ |s| s.update(status: 'paid') }
```

Hope this help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Try with this code:

```
Subscription.where(:status =>'closed').update_all(:status => 'paid')
```

OR

```
Subscription.where(status: 'closed').update_all(status: 'paid')
```